# Heroku app displays a blank white page on deploying a React Hasura GraphQL App

Tags: reactjs, api, heroku, graphql, hasura

I created a simple Schedule management app using Hasura GraphQL API and React. I tried to host my app on Heroku using CLI however, its not working propwerly. It displays a blank white page when I open it. I am using Heroku and GraphQL for the first time so I am unable to figure out what exactly am I doing wrong.

My Github Repository Link for my source code: https://github.com/yash-sethia/Schedule-Management-App-using-GraphQL-and-React

My heroku app link (That show's an error screen) : https://schedule-management-app.herokuapp.com/

These are the build logs of my app:

```
2020-11-12T23:37:16.884955+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.29.25.131 - - [12/Nov/2020:23:37:16 +0000] "GET /Schedule-Management-App-using-GraphQL-and-React/static/css/main.27c6850f.chunk.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://schedule-app121.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36"
2020-11-12T23:37:16.886137+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.227.185 - - [12/Nov/2020:23:37:16 +0000] "GET /Schedule-Management-App-using-GraphQL-and-React/static/css/2.2a86faee.chunk.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://schedule-app121.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36"
2020-11-12T23:37:17.189892+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/Schedule-Management-App-using-GraphQL-and-React/static/js/main.dcc84ac6.chunk.js" host=schedule-app121.herokuapp.com request_id=65988f5f-8747-493d-8f00-91cef9ae3ba6 fwd="182.64.168.27" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=168 protocol=https
2020-11-12T23:37:17.191882+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.227.185 - - [12/Nov/2020:23:37:17 +0000] "GET /Schedule-Management-App-using-GraphQL-and-React/static/js/main.dcc84ac6.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://schedule-app121.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36"
2020-11-12T23:37:17.195902+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/Schedule-Management-App-using-GraphQL-and-React/static/js/2.745ae571.chunk.js" host=schedule-app121.herokuapp.com request_id=f5ae2ec2-4aa6-44f9-bc3b-6e07682fd4e5 fwd="182.64.168.27" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=168 protocol=https
2020-11-12T23:37:17.196943+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.29.25.131 - - [12/Nov/2020:23:37:17 +0000] "GET /Schedule-Management-App-using-GraphQL-and-React/static/js/2.745ae571.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://schedule-app121.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36"
2020-11-12T23:37:18.675068+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/Schedule-Management-App-using-GraphQL-and-React/favicon.ico" host=schedule-app121.herokuapp.com request_id=232df477-6277-40fe-970d-3e97b3541355 fwd="182.64.168.27" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=168 protocol=https
2020-11-12T23:37:18.675593+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.227.185 - - [12/Nov/2020:23:37:18 +0000] "GET /Schedule-Management-App-using-GraphQL-and-React/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://schedule-app121.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36"
2020-11-12T23:37:23.523585+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.227.185 - - [12/Nov/2020:23:37:23 +0000] "GET /Schedule-Management-App-using-GraphQL-and-React/manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://schedule-app121.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36"
2020-11-12T23:37:23.542497+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/Schedule-Management-App-using-GraphQL-and-React/manifest.json" host=schedule-app121.herokuapp.com request_id=a643f987-bcdb-4bae-a8a6-d7d0faa408bc fwd="182.64.168.27" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=168 protocol=https
```

Comment: Does your app run properly on you local machine?

Comment: @squeezer44 Yes it runs perfectly on my local machine

Comment: I can only find statuscoes 304 in the log you have posted - no error. Please call your home URL https://schedule-management-app.herokuapp.com/ and post the specific error log in here.